# How to get reference to existing Mapbox GL map and marker?

Tags: mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

Basically, in a third-party js file which I can edit but would prefer not to edit:

```js
(function(){
    const map = new mapboxgl.Map({"container": "theMapNode", ...});
    const marker = new mapboxgl.Marker(...);
    marker.addTo(map);
})();
```

In my own code I want to do stuff like:

```js
if (pigs.fly && moon.is_blue) {
  map.setCenter(...);
  marker.getLngLat();
}
```

But I need to obtain the references to `map` and `marker` first. How can I do this?

I tried to look at the attributes of the `theMapNode` node, but I don't see anything obvious like `map` or `mapboxgl` or something.

Calling the constructor again with just `{container: "theMapNode"}` throws and error.

Searching the documentation didn't find this mentioned either. Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 2):

The short version is, you can't. That `map` variable is a local variable, so not accessible outside the context. And there isn't a way to access it from the DOM elements.